# Jenkins - Global Pipeline Library - Currently maps to revision

Tags: jenkins, global, jenkins-pipeline

I've a question about Jenkin's new Global Pipeline Library. If I define a library to be sourced from a Git repository it provides the following info

> Currently maps to revision: 300c6025caa1dc8fbb610addc1d7e43effcf2aa7

[image: Global Pipeline Library]

I've noticed that when a new commit is added to my library it's automatically picked up. But I'm not sure how? Nor have I found a description of how it works in the Jenkins documentation.

My best guess is that the Git repo is able to send Jenkins a notification when a commit is detected. Is this what actually happens? Or does Jenkins poll the repository?

Comment: I hate this functionality!! Changes to your library will trigger pipelines that consume it! Can't shut it off it seems!

Comment: You mean if a job uses @Library('myLibrary') _ and myLibrary gets a new commit it'll trigger that job?

Comment: Can you not use the Default Version to hard code the revision?

Comment: Change something in the library, push the change, execute your build again and have a look at the console. As far as I remember there is a git pull after you change the library (not 100% sure though)

Comment: yep! it includes the commit hash from the library!

Comment: What do you mean "is automatically picked up"? In your config, you've specified `master` as the version to use. So if you commit to master, the next time the job runs, it'll use the latest commit from master when checking out the library to use in the build.

Comment: I guess that's my question. I've assumed that it did an initial checkout and shared that between jobs. I've since learnt that may not be the case. So is it checking out the project everytime someone calls @Library("myLibrary")?